# Install PyQt5 on Mavericks

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm trying to install PyQt5 on my Mavericks machine.

I have tried to do it like in this link here [Installing PyQt5 with Python 3 On OS X](http://danmarner.com/2014/04/23/Installing-PyQt5-with-Python-3-On-OS-X.html)

When I try to install qt5 with brew, there comes a warning:

```
qt5-5.2.1 already installed
```

But then when I type `python configure.py`

Terminal says:

```
querying qmake about your Qt installation... Error: PyQt5 requires Qt
v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v4.8.6. Use the
--qmake flag to specify the correct version of quake.
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: So have you used the `-q` flag with a valid path to a `qmake` file?

Answer (score 10):

When you installed Qt via homebrew, you should have received a warning similar to:

```
This formula is keg-only, so it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Qt 5 conflicts Qt 4 (which is currently much more widely used).

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/qt5/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/qt5/include
```

While this information is very helpful, what you are specifically looking for will be in a directory under `/usr/local/opt/qt5/$VERSION_OF_QT/bin/` as `qmake` is a binary utility.

For me, `qmake` is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/bin/qmake`.  Take this path and feed it to your `--configure` switch and you'll be all set!

e.g. `python configure.py --qmake /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.1/bin/qmake`

Comment: I'd love to know why you weren't upvoted, but your information put me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: @jollyroger exactly which extension file location we need to put here

Comment: @FahadUddin: Not sure what you're asking for, but if you want to know where the files are located, you have to search for the files and pass that information to the build variables.